# Conditional overwrite of style property

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to alter the background of a textbox if the value of the field contains a specified text. The problem that I encounter is that I already have a style applied to the field and I try to overwrite a property of the style like in the following example but with no  success. Any ideas how could I achieve this?

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Text="{Binding CustomerType}" >

    <TextBox.Style BasedOn="{DynamicResource SelectableTextStyle}">
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CustomerType}" Value="Unknown">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Tomato"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: pls edit your post and add the Style definition for  `SelectableTextStyle`

Answer (score 0):

Your style definition, as written should probably not even compile because you are using an attribute on a property element (the TextBox.Style tag).

Update your code so that the inner style definition has the 'BasedOn' attribute like so:

```
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{DynamicResource SelectableTextStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
        ....
```

And everything will be gravy.